# Evaluate the following sum using the hyperbola method

Tags: number-theory

This is an exercise from Iwaniec and Kowalski's book Analytic Number Theory:

Prove that
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n \leq x} \tau(n^2 + 1) = \frac{3}{\pi}x \log x + O(x).$$

The constant $3/\pi$ is quite mysterious to me, and it doesn't seem like the hyperbola method can detect which numbers are divisors of a number of the form $n^2 + 1$. Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I forget what Iwaniec/Kowalski's notational convention is, is $\tau$ the sum of divisors function of Ramanujan's $\tau$ function?

Comment: I'm guessing based on the constant the ${3\over\pi}$ comes from ${\pi\over 2}\cdot\zeta(2)^{-1}$ which would be the Minkowski volume of a quarter of the unit disk in $\Bbb C$ times the probability two integers are relatively prime, which makes sense given you're looking for sums of squares, which usually happens in $\Bbb Z[i]$. This is based solely on experience though, I cannot find any paper to work it out, and this assumes $\tau$ is the sum of divisors function.

Comment: You can find some indications here: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/erdos-divisor-bound/

Comment: A sketch of the proof is also given in _Opera de Cribo_ pg 15